# Passing a pointer array as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, parameters

I can't find the correct syntax for passing a pointer array of type float *[] as a parameter to a function.

```
real * pp[] = { _osc[0].get_samples_ptr(), _osc[1].get_samples_ptr() };
_mod.iterate_sample_loop( samples, p_syn_ctx, pp );
```

is ok, but

```
_mod.iterate_sample_loop( samples, p_syn_ctx, 
                          { _osc[0].get_samples_ptr(), 
                            _osc[1].get_samples_ptr() } );
```

where iterate_sample_loop is:

```
void mod::iterate_sample_loop( u32 samples, 
                               synth_context * p_syn_ctx, 
                               real * p_inputs[] ) ...
```

results "error: expected primary-expression before 'xxx' token".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an array temporary with `{ _osc[0].get_samples_ptr(), _osc[1].get_samples_ptr() }`. AFAIK the only way to create an array temporary is like this:

```
typedef int array_type[3];

void f(int the_array[]) {}

int main() {
    f(array_type{1,3,4});
}
```

This only works in C++11, though. I think it's not possible at all in C++03.

Comment: I guess the answer uses C++11 uniform initialization, and you cannot achieve the same with C++98?

Comment: `typedef real * inputs[];`
...
`_mod.iterate_sample_loop(samples, p_syn_ctx, inputs { _osc[0].get_samples_ptr(), _osc[1].get_samples_ptr() } );`
gives the same error.

Comment: @AykutK. if you're not compiling in C++11 mode, you're out of luck.

Comment: thanks for the tip. upgrading to gcc 4 and adding -std=c++0x param to compiler fixed.